# How to load a field from a user that is being viewed

Tags: theming, users

I am looking to load a field from a user's profile that is being viewed.For example, I am looking at another users profile and it will load their associated field.

I am programmatically adding a picture to the tpl (probably should be template.php) and then I am adding it to the background-image of a div. My code loads the user but then switches the user to user being viewed. It is obviously not good to be able to switch users.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   $user = user_load(arg(1));
   $picture = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_picture');
   $file = $picture['filename'];
   $url = $base_url . '/files/' . $file;
<?
```

I cannot find a secure way to do this. Anyone have an idea?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a [user-profile.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7) file in your theme and messing around with that.

Default contents are:

```
<div class="profile">
  <?php print $user_profile; ?>
</div>
```

And I suggest using a variable name other than $user as $user is a global variable referring to the logged in user.

Comment: I have two custom pages to process profiles. One for the logged on user and another for the user to view other profiles. Each one queries a little different things. I maybe could look into merging the two. This code is all in my page--user--%.tpl.php file. $user-profile isn't loading anything in there when I print it.

Comment: Ah right, so you need to load variables for your custom pages in a preprocess function.

Comment: It actually seems to be working by changing the name of the $user variable. Just one question before closing this up, is there any security implications I should consider with this?

Comment: Really depends on what you are trying to do.  If the pages are forms or they show personal details of users you probably want to set an access_callback which uses either a pre-existing permission or a new one you create using hook_permission.  Other than that, what are you worried might happen?

Comment: I am just spooked from the fact the code was automatically switching user when you visited their page. Now I am paranoid haha